# Load border from xml with dimension

Tags: xml, border, dimension

I have an xml file where have a few areas border defined. The problem is that border points for each area is not defined by many tag's

```
<point> lat lon </point>
<point> lat lon </point>
<point> lat lon </point>
<point> lat lon >/point>
```

but in one looong tag

```
<poslist> lat1 lon1 lat2 lon2 lat3 lon3 lat4 lon4 ..... (and so on) </poslist>
```

How to parse such file?

Regards
Skorek

Comment: What programming tools do you have at hand? XPath? JavaScript? Python?

Comment: Javascript but if you have an answer in PHP, Python also send :-)

Answer (score 0):

In python (2.7) have a file `latlon.py`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def text2tuple(coordstr, convert=float):
    """ takes space delimited string and converts to tuple, converting each item

    >>> text2tuple("alfa beta", str)
    ("alfa", "beta")
    >>> text2tuple("1.1 2.2 3.3", float)
    (1.1, 2.2, 3.3)
    """
    return map(convert, coordstr.split())

def zip2couples(lst):
    """ for list of items return half lenght list of couples
    >>> zip2couples(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
    """
    return zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2])

def processxmlstr(xmlstr, convert=float):
    xmldoc = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)
    print "points", [text2tuple(itm.text, convert) for itm in xmldoc.findall(".//point")]
    print "poslists", [zip2couples(text2tuple(itm.text, convert)) for itm in xmldoc.findall(".//poslist")]

print "string values test -----"
xmlstr = """
<root>
  <point>lat lon</point>
  <point>lat lon</point>
  <point>lat lon</point>
  <point>lat lon</point>
  <poslist>lat1 lon1 lat2 lon2 lat3 lon3 lat4 lon4</poslist>
</root>
"""
processxmlstr(xmlstr, str)

print "float values test -----"
xmlstr = """
<root>
  <point>1.1 11.11</point>
  <point>2.2 22.22</point>
  <point>3.3 33.33</point>
  <point>4.4 44.44</point>
  <poslist>10.1 99.1 10.2 99.2 10.3 99.3</poslist>
  <poslist>20.1 88.1 20.2 88.2 20.3 88.3</poslist>
</root>
"""
processxmlstr(xmlstr, float)
```

Run it from console:

```
$ python latlon.py
string values test -----
points [['lat', 'lon'], ['lat', 'lon'], ['lat', 'lon'], ['lat', 'lon']]
poslists [[('lat1', 'lon1'), ('lat2', 'lon2'), ('lat3', 'lon3'), ('lat4', 'lon4')]]
float values test -----
points [[1.1, 11.11], [2.2, 22.22], [3.3, 33.33], [4.4, 44.44]]
poslists [[(10.1, 99.1), (10.2, 99.2), (10.3, 99.3)], [(20.1, 88.1), (20.2, 88.2), (20.3, 88.3)]]
```

Comment: Thanks, if you havn't solution in javascript I'll try use python :-)